# Execute JavaScript on radmenu click asp.net

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using rad menu (telerik) in my website. the menu items are binding to menu in code behind. i take the navigate URL from database and the navigate URL will be sometimes a `JavaScript` like

```
js=OpenSupportWin();
```

Instead of page url.
So  when I give this to navigateurl nothing is happening. please help me to solve this.

```
 private void GenerateVerticalMenuTelerik(string pParentMenuId, RadMenuItem rmi)
    {
        List<DBMenus> ListVerticalMenus = new List<DBMenus>();
        ListVerticalMenus = MenuGenerator.GetVerticalMainMenusFromNode(pParentMenuId, ClsLogin.Instance.IsAuthenticated());

        if (ListVerticalMenus != null)
        {
            foreach (DBMenus asVertical in ListVerticalMenus)
            {
                try
                {

                    bool IsSelectedVertical = (m_SelectedMenuPath.SelectedSubItemId == asVertical.SiteMapNodeId);

                    RadMenuItem rmItem = new RadMenuItem();
                    rmItem.Text = asVertical.WORDINGTextTitle;

                    rmItem.NavigateUrl = PII.ToolWeb.Tools.pkFunctions.GetPageLinkURL(asVertical.SiteMapNodeUrl);
                    rmi.Items.Add(rmItem);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show me your code , how did you bind your Menu Item ?

Comment: Updated the question with code sample...

Comment: Will `PII.ToolWeb.Tools.pkFunctions.GetPageLinkURL(asVertical.SiteMapNodeUrl);` return  `OpenSupportWin()` sometime ?

Comment: No. it shows url?js=OpenSupportWin();

Answer (score 0):

string url_js = asVertical.SiteMapNodeUrl;

```
                    if (url_js.Contains("js"))
                    {
                        url_js = url_js.Replace("?js=", "");
                        url_js = url_js.Replace(";", "");
                        url_js = "javascript:" + url_js;
                    }
```

i wrote these lines of code and it works for me

Answer (score -1):

Set your navigateUrl to something like this:

```
  item.NavigateUrl = "javascript:OpenSupportWin();";
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work. The method appears to be that you should write a handler for the click on the Menu itself, then figure which item has been clicked and then do something about.

Comment: Which version of the controls are you using?  I have sample code in the 2013 Q2 version that is executing it properly.  See this Gist:  https://gist.github.com/csharpfritz/6132027

Comment: i tried the code in this link. https://gist.github.com/csharpfritz/6132027.it works, but when it call a function it won't work. in my case i  have two master pages and the reference is mapped in parent master page and setting the menu url from child master page

Comment: string url_js = asVertical.SiteMapNodeUrl;

                        if (url_js.Contains("js"))
                        {
                            url_js = url_js.Replace("?js=", "");
                            url_js = url_js.Replace(";", "");
                            url_js = "javascript:" + url_js;
                        }